# How to fix "HTTP Error 400: Bad Request" for Amazon api request in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-product-api

I am an Python beginner and trying to make an Amazon-Api-Request using Python 3.x with Anaconda and get this response. I spend a lot of time trying to fix the issue but dindnt come up with an solution.
strong text

INPUT:

```
from amazon.api import AmazonAPI

AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY = "..."
AMAZON_SECRET_KEY = "..."
AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG = "..."

amazon = AmazonAPI(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY, AMAZON_SECRET_KEY, AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG)

products = amazon.search(Keywords="knoblauchpresse", SearchIndex='All')
for i, product in enumerate(products):
    print(product.title, product.list_price, product.asin)
```

OUTPUT:

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-84eb43d7eab0> in <module>
      8 
      9 products = amazon.search(Keywords="knoblauchpresse", SearchIndex='All')
---> 10 for i, product in enumerate(products):
     11     print(product.title, product.list_price, product.asin)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/amazon/api.py in __iter__(self)
    542             Yields a :class:`~.AmazonProduct` for each result item.
    543         """
--> 544         for page in self.iterate_pages():
    545             for item in getattr(page.Items, 'Item', []):
    546                 yield AmazonProduct(

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/amazon/api.py in iterate_pages(self)
    559             while not self.is_last_page:
    560                 self.current_page += 1
--> 561                 yield self._query(ItemPage=self.current_page, **self.kwargs)
    562         except NoMorePages:
    563             pass
```

...

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Comment: is this official module from Amazon page ? Maybe Amazon changed something in API and this module doesn't know it.

Comment: HI @furas thanks for your comment! I think so yes. How can I check that?

Comment: It looks like it's a wrapper from this Github: https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api and the last release was over a year ago.  Might be like @furas said and it could have some deprecated stuff

Comment: Hi @MichaelPlatt do you now a better wrapper which works?

Comment: I found this one online https://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html# that looks pretty good.  Might work out better for you

Comment: You could also just use Python's standard `request` library and write your own requests using the Amazon API directly like seen here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html

Comment: @MichaelPlatt i installed the package typing "pip install python-amazon-product-api" into the terminal and tried the following code: 

import amazonproduct
config = {
    'access_key': '...',
    'secret_key': '...',
    'associate_tag': '...',
    'locale': 'us'
}
api = amazonproduct.API(cfg=config)

But again i get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'amazonproduct'"

Comment: I'm assuming it didn't work for you since it's just the code you posted in the comment?  Have you tried the simple example they have? `api = API(locale='us')
items = api.item_search('Books', Publisher="O'Reilly")`  It could be your search criteria that aren't good.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt it returns "NameError: name 'API' is not defined"

Comment: Just use the second part.  Didn't see that you had already brought in the `api` object and configured it.  So just try the query itself  `items = api.item_search('Books', Publisher="O'Reilly")`

Comment: @MichaelPlatt returns: "NameError: name 'api' is not defined"

Comment: You are sure you can actually import the `amazonproduct`?  So if you open a terminal and type `python` to get into the Python terminal and then run `import amazonproduct` do you get an error?

Comment: >>> import amazonproduct
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'amazonproduct'
>>> pip install python-amazon-product-api
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install python-amazon-product-api
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> pip install python-amazon-product-api

Comment: I have a bad feeling. Which Python version are you using? If you're using Python 3, which I presume you do, then this library will not install because its author (me) has not found the time to do a proper release for Python 3 yet.

Comment: Have you tried using [Bottlenose](https://github.com/lionheart/bottlenose)? That seems like a more recent package to achieve your goal.